# VBA - open a single .csv file in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a .csv using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.
My file is saved in a Downloads folder and there is only 1 file in that folder. Because the file name changes over, so I use the wildcard.

I am using the following code.

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & "*.csv"
```

Comment: You cant just do the `*` wildcard, look at `dir`

Comment: The code looks completely alright . Wildcard will pick the first file on the directory. Have you checked whether the path exists ?  Could you explain about the error a little bit ?

Comment: Hi manoj0709, it said "Sorry, we couldn't find...., is it possible it was moved,...".
I tried with a file specific directory then it works, but the error comes up when I change the file name to a wildcard *.csv

Comment: You can use `Environ$("userprofile")` instead of `"C:\Users\" & Environ$("username")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dir() to find the filename, then open using workbook.open.

```
Fname = Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & "*.csv")
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & Fname
```

Or combine the two:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & Dir("C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\" & "*.csv")
```